# Call window.load function after AJAX has completed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using a wordpress theme that has lots of styling options etc which is read by the header.php file and does styling and some js stuff based on that. For example, here is a snippet of what it looks like:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
<?php if($data['blog_pagination_type'] == 'Infinite Scroll' || is_page_template('demo-gridblog.php')  || is_page_template('demo-timelineblog.php')): ?>
    jQuery('#posts-container').infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : "div.pagination",
                       // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
        nextSelector : "a.pagination-next",
                       // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector : "div.post",
                       // selector for all items you'll retrieve
        errorCallback: function() {
            jQuery('#posts-container').isotope('reLayout');
        }
    }
    });
});
```

This is a snippet but there is a lot more. This is in my header.php file. I then do some AJAX calls in my custom.js file. It looks something like this:

```
var term_id = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl,
  type: "POST",
  async: true,
  cache: true,
  data: {
    action: 'show_blog',
    term_id: term_id
  },
  success: function(data) {   
      jQuery(window).load();
      $('.blog-wrapper').fadeOut(1000, function() {
          $('.blog-wrapper').html(data);
          $(".blog-wrapper").fadeIn(1000);
      });
  }
});
```

I tried to use `jQuery(window).load();` but the JS from my header.php file doesn't get triggered. How can I re-trigger the `window.load` code in my header.php file after the AJAX call? Do I need to put it in a different function and then do something like this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
    do_styling_function();
});
```

Then in my AJAX call I can also just call `do_styling_function();`?

Comment: [`jQuery(window).trigger('load');`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger)

Comment: Or `jQuery(window).triggerHandler('load')` http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

Comment: @Blazemonger If you want to put up an answer I can accept it. What you said worked great. I added the complete function to my ajax call and put that in there and it worked perfectly. I had to remove the fadein and fadeout functions though in the success function to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just trigger the `onload` event in the usual manner:

```
jQuery(window).trigger('load');
```