# Flexslider: animation:slide not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am using flexslider and I am having problem with its animation:slide effect. It only works if I leave the page and come again or if the page lose and gain the focus. The navigations arrow are showing fine they actually detect the click event. The small dots in the bottom also clickable and they actually get active once I click on them but no image transition happens.

UPDATE: It do not works on the dynamic content, i-e when the slide html comes via ajax

Any help please. Here is my code;

```
          var options = {  
            animation: "slide"
        };

        $('.team-pages-slider').flexslider(options);

        $.ajax({
                            url:  href,
                            dataType: "html",
                            cache: false,
                            beforeSend:function(data){
                            $('.global-loader').show();
                        },
                        success: function(data){


            $content.html(data);
            loadFlexJS();

)};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use callback success from $.ajax. Check on [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

I don't know flexslider, but i guesses:

1. Load library js in header of page
2. Call $.ajax function
3. On callback success start flexslider

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149059/call-window-load-function-after-ajax-has-completed) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

ok I find a fix for this. I put the flexslideJS() into a setimer function. So the flexslider code will be executed after 1 second so the html should be on the page.

```
 setTimeout(function(){

                App.teamPageSlider();

    }, 1000);
```

Comment: what if ajax is taking 2 seconds to respond?

Answer (score 0):

Placement of your slider initializing code is wrong.

`$('.team-pages-slider').flexslider(options);` should be placed inside ajax success method.

```
var options = {  
    animation: "slide"
};

$.ajax({
    url:  href,
    dataType: "html",
    cache: false,
    beforeSend:function(data){
        $('.global-loader').show();
    },
    success: function(data){
        $content.html(data);
        loadFlexJS();
        $('.team-pages-slider').flexslider(options);
    }
})
```